# Pandas read_csv dropping duplicate header rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple csv in cloud which I have to download as bytes. Those csv's are all equals in format so I'm expecting always the same number of data.

```
itemid            timestamp                   y              y_lower
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
itemid            timestamp                   y              y_lower
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
itemid            timestamp                   y              y_lower
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
43406  2023-05-29T16:00:00   27.61612174350883   4.7486855702091635
```

```py
            dataset_bytes_array, dataset_metadata = download_object_directory_bytes(
                dataset_storage.bucket_name, prefix=f'{dataset_storage.object_path}/datasets',
            )
            dataset_bytes_data = b''.join(dataset_bytes_array)
```

After obtaining the final bytes array, I create a Pandas dataframe in the following way:

```py
                dataset_df = pd.read_csv(
                    BytesIO(dataset_bytes_data), on_bad_lines='warn', keep_default_na=False, dtype=object,
                )
```

I thought that `on_bad_lines` could help me skip the duplicate header rows but this doesn't seem to happen. Is there a very generic way to drop duplicate header rows?

Comment: If these are independent csvs, why don't you read as different dataframes and then do a union of them?

Answer (score 0):

First locate the index values of duplicate headers and then drop them.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'itemid':['itemid',1,2,3,'itemid',4,5,6],'timestamp':['timestamp',1,2,3,'timestamp',4,5,6]})
print(df)

    itemid  timestamp
-----------------------
0   itemid  timestamp
1        1          1
2        2          2
3        3          3
4   itemid  timestamp
5        4          4
6        5          5
7        6          6

header_loc=df[df['itemid']=='itemid'].index
df.drop(header_loc,inplace=True)
print(df)

    itemid  timestamp
-----------------------
1        1          1
2        2          2
3        3          3
5        4          4
6        5          5
7        6          6
```

Update -1: without hardcoding column name

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df['itemid'],errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

Comment: This works but I need this to be as generic is possible. I can't hardcore the column name to find the header location